# .Net Solution: Build Steps for windows services

Tags: c#, wcf, msbuild, nant

I have created 2 WCF service libraries in a solution.  I have also created two windows services which will host the two wcf services.

these wcf services communicate with eachother. one gets requests and is reusable service for other systems, the other service sends requests to this service and takes requests from the UI.

I have created installers for the window services too.

I want to understand the build script tasks which I need to include which I will call during each time I want to deploy this solution to the server?

Should I delete all of the windows services and install again with new DLLs?

What is the best way

Comment: How did you implement the installer? If you are using an MSI installer, it will automatically remove/recreate the service during an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to delete the windows services. You can stop the service, replace the service executable and all the assemblies used by your service and restart the service. This is what I've always done, and I've never run into problems.

Comment: thanks. have you used quartz.net? my windows service is running quartz.net and i had a question related to it

Comment: I haven't used quartz.net. I think you'll need to look into what windows actually registers for the service. As long as the executable that the service is expecting is the same, you shouldn't have any issues. Creating a bat file that will unregister and register the service isn't difficult either, so you may want to try that option if your running into issues with the service starting after replacing the files the service depends on.